# VBA Code throwing errors which are fixed by copying and pasting

Tags: excel, vba

I have code in an Excel workbook which is in Modules and which is implemented via a Userform. The workbook is a template workbook so when colleagues use it they take a copy and work in their own copies of it. They use a separate copy for each client so in essence, there are hundreds of copies of it in use at any one time.

The interface and code have been working fine for about 2 years but in the past week I have had a 2 cases flagged to me with various errors occuring. When I've stepped through the code it has been throwing errors in different places.

In the first incident, a string variable wasn't retaining the correct value:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name is '" & name & "';"
```

After this line executing, the value of `sSQL` was "SELECT * FROMJohn Johnson", i.e. it had lopped off parts of the string. No error was thrown at this point  but in the next line the `sSQL` string variable is an argument in a `recordset.open` function call. As `sSQL` is an incoherent select statement,  `rs.open` threw a SELECT statement error.

This was confusing as nothing had changed in the code and it had always worked before. I copied and repasted the line and this fixed the problem - the second line ran without issue, `sSQL` had the correct value so `rs.open` worked.

The day after I had another case flagged to me - so a copy of the same template workbook but a different copy from the one the previous day. The error was the same and it was being caused by another `sSQL` string not retaining the correct value but in a different `Sub` elsewhere in the code. I fixed this in the same way - by copying and repasting the line which assigns the value to `sSQL`. Again this fixed the issue.

However, in the same workbook I encountered another error further on in the code. This time it was an `If` statement causing the error:

```
Private Sub setAuthoriser(Optional s As String)
'sets or clears the Authoriser name on signoff data sheet
    If IsMissing(s) Or s = "" Then
        Sheet3.Cells(16, 6).ClearContents
    Else
        Sheet3.Cells(16, 6).Value = s
    End If
End Sub
```

When `If IsMissing(s) Or s = "" Then` executes I get the following error:

*Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.*

Whether I click Degug or End on the warning message, the workbook then closes.

Again, code has worked consistently before and can be fixed by copying and repasting the code and deleting the original lines.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening here or have you encountered something similar before? I'm really stuck...

Comment: I bet it is either a corrupted installation of Office (check if it works on other computers using the exact same file) or it is a corrupted Excel file which can easily happen whith the `xlsm` or `xlsx` format. Try to save a file that does not work properly as `xlsb` and see if this fixes it. The binary `xlsb` format is much more stable as the `xlsm`/`xlsx` format and even produces smaller files. • Also check the harddrives the files were saved to. If there is errors in the file system or sectors this might cause corrupted files too. Do checkdisk and check SMART status!

Comment: AS we are working from home they are different virtual desktops as opposed to different computers, not sure if that makes a difference. I saved as `xlsb` and that didn't fix. Unfortunately I am not in IT so don't have admin access so can't do any diagnositics on the hard drives! I tried saving to another folder and still get the errors.

Comment: Yes the issue is once the file is broken it's hard to get them fixed again. Get someone from IT involed for this! That's why you have those guys, they should be able to help and to run the diagnostics. Get it escalated. It doesn't help if you fight the symptoms. You (your company) needs to find the **root cause** and fix it. If you can't get the people involved who can!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that bevor. Sometimes modules get corrupted.
Internal there is Code you do not see.

One Way is to Copy the Code to an Editor then delete the code (STRG + A + Del) and copy it back.

Or Export the module and import it again could help, but I prefer the copy method.

You could write yourself a Code using VBE and replacing the Code, if there are many modules. That what I do sometimes with old projects.

Comment: Do you mean manually C & P the code or write some code to do it? Is that even possible to do programmatically on module code? Ideally I need a solution that I can code in the template workbook so individual copies can be fixed as/when they break. Allowing users to manually copy and paste the code themselves isn't an option as they are not able/allowed to access the code

Comment: But if you do it in the template then if a workbook is created from the template should be fixed (if that was the reason) And for the VBE just google for programming the vbe. You can write code by code this is not a problem (Make sure to trust the VBA Project Model in the Macro settings)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, yes, you can do it manually.